# MongoDB queries from java client is super fast compared to mongo shell command line

Tags: java, mongodb

Implementing a mongo load generator.

Query from command line or other clients like robomongo:

```
db.getCollection('load_test').find().sort({'col_inner.col9a': 1}).limit(50)
```

Time consumed : approx 25- 30 seconds

Query from java client:

```
collection.find().sort(ascending("col_inner.col9a")).limit(50);
```

Time Consumed : approx 3ms

How could Java client take so less time for the same query?

Comment: Your Java code is just getting a query cursor, not the actual documents. Iterate over the cursor for a comparable test.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, Thanks a lot for your reply! That worked! If I traverse through the docs with the cursor, it takes about 25 - 30 sec.
Although I would like to understand,
Does MongoDB hit the database to fetch each and every document one by one during traversal unlike relational DB ResultSet, where rows are fetched into the memory.

Comment: No, the docs are fetched in [batches](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/cursors/#cursor-batches).

Comment: Really appreciate your quick response @JohnnyHK
Thanks a ton !